# Clojure: Insert spaces into string every x chars

Tags: string, clojure

I have a long clojure String, and I need to split it with spaces every 2 characters (ex: "1234567890" --> "12 34 56 78 90".
The solution I used is:

```
(->>
  (partition 2 2 "" s)
  (map (partial join ""))
  (join " "))
```

Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with regex, but is this simpler? For me - yes, but it looks like a matter of taste.

```
user> (clojure.string/replace "1234567890" #"(.{2})(?!$)" "$1 ")
"12 34 56 78 90"
```

Comment: It is indeed neat but if I were going to use it, I will leave a considerable amount of comment to help the future devs (and myself)! :)

Comment: @Chiron, of course regex always kinda write-only code, but this one is small and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible variant:

```
user=> (->> "1234567890" (partition 2) (map #(apply str %))
            (clojure.string/join " "))
"12 34 56 78 90"
```

Comment: @Chiron define 'simpler'. For one it may be using async, someone will use java interop, transducers or web service. I posted 'simpler' solution for me. Author will decide if it's simpler for him or not.

Comment: the person wrote a regexp and call it *simpler* solution. It's subjective.

Comment: Of course it IS subjective, but regex is a standart tool to do text transformations. And here we have sting -> seq of seqs -> seq of strings -> new string. And we also uset 2 macros, to do such simple thing. I don't know, must be really interesting definition of simplicity.